# Zen coding support for CSS in Web Essentials 2012 for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, emmet, web-essentials

i'Ve installed web essentials 2012 for VS2012.
But it seems it doesen't support zen coding for css??
or am i missing something??
please help..
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Essentials only supports ZenCoding for HTML. I decided to wait with the CSS implementation because of the CSS editors rich Intellisense and snippet support. They would most likely conflict with ZenCoding

Comment: also please mention somewhere that you need to TAB to get it to expand.  not at all obvious to beginners (like me)

Comment: Jaysun, i was just asking for the zen coding support for css and now the way it's done. Well, if you wanna check out the documentation go here http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample to try :

```
h1{Good Example}#test.classname+#sibling1{div sibling1 text}+#sibling2{div sibling2 text}+h2{header2 text}+ul>li>a[href="http://stackoverflow.com"]{stackoverflow link}^li>a[href="http://codeproject.com"]{codeproject link}
```

**Hit [TAB] Key to Expand**

Remember to hit [tab] key after typing the sample, to expand the zen code to real HTML.

The sample above will expand to the following:

[image: Zen code expanded html view]

It will render in the browser to look like this:

[image: Zen code html render view]